# Advantages of cakePHP CLI?

Tags: cakephp, command-line

1. What are the advantages of using cakePHP's CLI?
2. Is it good to start learning cakePHP using CLI than starting with the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1528/Blog)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1. What are the advantages of using cakePHP's CLI?**

- Using the CLI to bake models/controllers/views can get a project up and running quickly.
- The CLI also comes in handy for managing accounts/permissions until you absolutely need a UI for those things.

The disadvantage relates to your second point.

- If you bake a php application using the command line, you may have something up and running quickly, but you won't really have learned anything in the process.  If you're going for deeper learning, avoid the CLI and go through some tutorials.

Comment: +1. Start with the blog tutorial if you want to learn CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI is extremely handy for running cron jobs. You can create custom Cake console tasks and then your cron jobs can rely on unit-tested code which has access to your app's Cake-based models.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of advantage or disadvantage. The Cake console is a tool. Whether you use that tool, or not, is entirely up to you. Personally I rarely use it, and then just to build (bake) big datamodels.

I'm sure there are things it'll do that I'm unaware of, but pretty much anything you want to do you can do without it.

The choice is yours.